# Why is CQL allowing inequality operators with partition key?

Tags: cassandra, cql

The documentation is clear that the only operators allowed in a `SELECT` for use with a partition column are equals (`=`) and `in[value1, values2[,...])`, however, with `ALLOW FILTERING`, it seems inequality operators are allowed. Here's a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    emp_no      INT,
    dept_no     VARCHAR,
    from_date   DATE,
    to_date     DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, dept_no)
);

insert into dept_emp (emp_no, dept_no, from_date, to_date) values
(1, '9', '1901-01-01', '1920-02-01');
insert into dept_emp (emp_no, dept_no, from_date, to_date) values
(2, '9', '1920-01-01', '1930-01-01');
insert into dept_emp (emp_no, dept_no, from_date, to_date) values
(3, '9', '1920-01-01', '1930-01-01');

SELECT * FROM dept_emp WHERE emp_no > 1 ALLOW FILTERING;

 emp_no | dept_no | from_date  | to_date
--------+---------+------------+------------
      2 |       9 | 1920-01-01 | 1930-01-01
      3 |       9 | 1920-01-01 | 1930-01-01

(2 rows)
```

I took the document as describing what the CQL parser would recognize and so was expecting a error like I get if I try a `!=` operator. If this is just an `ALLOW FILTERING` thing, is it documented elsewhere what operators are allowed in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The partition key is in token order so things like `>` require reading the entire data set from all replica sets, filtering out things dont match. This is horribly inefficient and expensive (which is why ALLOW FILTERING is required). The same would be true of !=, generally C* will out right refuse to do any operation that requires reading *everything* as its simply something that database is not designed for. ALLOW FILTERING allows some cases of this for things like Spark jobs but they should be avoided in everything but random single run operational debugging tasks or well thought out olap jobs.

Equality on the partition key is required to have any semblance of an efficient query for the coordinator to know where to send the request. I would highly recommend only using equality and changing your data model such that you can satisfy queries that way.

Comment: I'm asking why Cassandra isn't throwing an error even when ALLOWING FILTERING is on. The docs indicate it isn't supported.

Comment: Really everything used under `allow filtering` is hit and miss (there were some bugs around this recently as well). Its so strongly recommended against that theres a bit of a stigma and lack of testing. Theres been many attempts to remove it but theres a few edge cases its useful. while < and > are allowed and work its likely because of its being used by spark and secondary indexes, the `!=` case is probably just never exercised by anyone who is willing to maintain the code change.

Comment: Thanks. This helps.